# Flutter error: I/Timeline(16820): Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:54370667 intent:Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: flutter, camera, imagepicker

My application  when tries to capture image or photo with camera , after the capture a black screen comes and My App is getting crashed and some times on  my app screen the following error shows in Orrange colour [enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP64k.jpg                                                                           Folowing errors are shwn when i debug my App                                                                     I/Timeline(16820): Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:54370667 intent:Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 clip={text/uri-list U:content://example.up.sign.loyd.app.example.flutter.com.signupexample.flutter.image_provider/external_files/Android/data/example.up.sign.loyd.app.example.flutter.com.signupexample/files/Pictures/82431e75-56bc-432f-8cfb-7ad25713ed59208646117.jpg} (has extras) }
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(16820): reportFullscreenMode on inexistent InputConnection
Lost connection to device.

I am already using  import libraries or  packages like

import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

in pebspeq.yaml I have used
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
image_picker: ^0.6.7+11
image_cropper: ^1.3.1
easy_permission_validator: ^1.0.5

Please suggest me a solution and fix my issue